# Newline is converted to space in facets

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am facing problem while getting facets, when I execute query directly on Solr, facet data is correct but through SolrNet, all '\n' converted to space.

I took the latest update of SolrNet library(1.0.12.0), but the problem still remains. The same field is working fine with regular document select through SolrNet, the problem is only with facet.

What could be the possible reason?
https://www.screencast.com/t/oWb1TvudME9M (\n is used as separator)

Note: Field type is : "**Strings**"

Comment: Are you outputting this in HTML? In that case, newlines are represented as a single space. Do you have something that shows the actual error as well?

Comment: @MatsLindh No I am not outputting this in HTML, I am splitting values by \n and assigning data in different properties, I am using C#. There is no error, Solr call is successful and data is coming, but with spaces :(

Comment: Then there's something wrong either in Solrnet, or in how your code is handling the values after splitting. The response from Solr itself seems to be as you'd expect.